# AngularJS Jasmine - Test with different Mock Response in next 'it' block

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

```
describe('test mock', function () {

    var resource, employeeRoles, provider, mockBaseUrl, mockUser, mockOffices, mockCalendar, $window, $httpBackend, $scope, $serializer;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('appointmentManager'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $rootScope, $httpParamSerializer) {


        mockCalendar = {
     // sample data
            };


        $window = $injector.get('$window');
        $window.ApiBaseUrl = mockBaseUrl;
        $window.LoggedInUser = mockUser;

        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
        $httpBackend.expectPOST('api/Calendar/GetCalendar').respond(200, mockCalendar);


        $scope.$apply();

        $httpBackend.flush();
    }));

    it('should be defined in module', function () {
        expect(resource).toBeDefined();
        expect(provider).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('active employees should be true', function () {
        expect(provider.isNoActiveEmployeesAvailable).toBe(false);

        //test with another mockCalendar data 
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        $scope.$destroy();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
});
```

I want to test with different Mock Response in Next `it` block. Here, how can I assign new value in `mockCalendar` variable before the second `it` block runs?

Comment: can't you just have have another `describe` instead of `it`.. that way you can specify different `beforeEach` inside it for both and have different mock data too

Comment: @tanmay is there no other way???

Comment: Don't think so. Though you can wrap your `beforeEach` in a function accepting `mockCalender` as param and reuse it to avoid code duplication

Comment: @tanmay how can i do that?

Comment: just call a function with `$injector` and `mockCalender` (new data for each `describe`) where the function contains all `beforeEach` related code.. or maybe try something with [this approach](http://codepen.io/lodybo/pen/xVVWPO?editors=0010#0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario, which is not uncommon, I typically create a function that has code that is going to be common in all my tests, and then call it from your test, *after* additional arrangements that cannot be performed in the `beforeEach`. Note this is different than using the `beforeEach`, because you still need to be able to modify something prior to calling the function.

For instance, your code would be modified to be like the following:

```
describe('test mock', function () {

    var resource, employeeRoles, provider, mockBaseUrl, mockUser, mockOffices, mockCalendar, $window, $httpBackend, $scope, $serializer;

    var setupTest = function(mockCalendar) {
        $httpBackend.expectPOST('api/Calendar/GetCalendar').respond(200, mockCalendar);
        $scope.$apply();
        $httpBackend.flush();
    };

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('appointmentManager'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $rootScope, $httpParamSerializer) {
        mockCalendar = {
          // sample data
        };

        $window = $injector.get('$window');
        $window.ApiBaseUrl = mockBaseUrl;
        $window.LoggedInUser = mockUser;

        $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    }));

    it('should be defined in module', function () {
        setupTest(mockCalendar); // not sure if this is needed here.
        expect(resource).toBeDefined();
        expect(provider).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should set provider.isNoActiveEmployeesAvailable to false when xxx', function () {
        mockCalendar.someField = 'some value';
        setupTest(mockCalendar);
        expect(provider.isNoActiveEmployeesAvailable).toBe(false);
    });

    it('should do something else', function () {
        mockCalendar.someField = 'some other value';
        setupTest(mockCalendar);
        expect(provider.isNoActiveEmployeesAvailable).toBe(true);
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        $scope.$destroy();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
});
```